# Find all children nodes of a particular node until the leaf node

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm new to Neo4j and trying to figure out a way to get all the children nodes of a node. Here's my graph model:
[Graph Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6LKR.png)

As you can see, the root node is an **SecurityGroup** node which may have **SecurityGroup** nodes under it or **User** nodes under it. I need to find all the children nodes(both User and SecurityGroups) of the root **SecurityGroup** node until there is no more nesting.

Comment: Hi@ironMan. If any of the answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can get all the descendant nodes (according to your graph model)) of a `SecurityGroup` node with the `id` property value of `123`.

```
MATCH (sg:SecurityGroup)<-[*]-(d)
WHERE sg.id = 123
RETURN d;
```

You may want to create an index (or uniqueness constraint) on `:SecurityGroup(id)` to initiate the query efficiently (rather than scanning all `SecurityGroup` nodes).

Comment: Thanks! That worked! However, some security groups still appear as disconnected when I run this query. On double clicking the security group nodes, they get connected back to other nodes in the graph. No new nodes are added though, just new edges get loaded. Can you explain why?

Comment: Your data model image showed all relationships pointing in the direction of the "root" node, so my query also requires the same directionality. That might explain why some "connected" nodes are not returned. If you want to disregard directionality, you can omit the `<` character from the query. Also, the neo4j browser will show all the "neighbors" of a node (up to a configurable limit) when you double-click on a node.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find all the children nodes(both User and SecurityGroups) **of
>   the root SecurityGroup** node until there is no more nesting.

If you want **only the children nodes from the ROOT node** you will need specify this condition in your query providing an ID-like property or a specific label for the root node (e.g. :RootNode, :Root, etc.).

Is not a good idea use the ID property generated by neo4j because it [can change](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#_get_node_or_relationship_by_id).

Using a `:Root` label in your root node you can do:

```
MATCH (:Root)<-[:BELONGS_TO*]-(c)
RETURN c
```

Is a good idea to specify the relationship name inside "[" and "]" by semantics questions and to improve performance.

Alternatively to :Root label and ID property you can install and use [GraphAware Neo4j UUID](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) that creates and manages universal unique identifiers for each node in your graph.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I'm planning to add some more nodes types in the graph, so there would be more than one type of relationships in my graph. Would it be possible to use multiple relationship names in that case?

Comment: Hello! Yes, you can match [by multiple relationships types](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#_match_by_multiple_relationship_types), e.g.:
`MATCH (:Root)<-[:BELONGS_TO|:ANOTHER_TYPE*]-(c)`